# VBA loop to transfer excel data to powerpoint table error

Tags: vba, loops, powerpoint

Been trying to get a loop to work just to save writing out many lines of code for each individual cell reference, but I keep getting 'Object doesn't support this property or method' and I can't seem to get it to work.

My code is:

```
'cycles through excel table and imports into powerpoint
For ranking = 2 To 11

    With oPPTShape.Table

        .Cells(ranking, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(ranking + 2, 1).Text 'store
        .Cells(ranking, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(ranking + 2, 2).Text 'Loan Value TY
        .Cells(ranking, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(ranking + 2, 3).Text 'Proportion of total Credit Sales
        .Cells(ranking, 5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(ranking + 2, 4).Text ' Accepted Apps 2017
        .Cells(ranking, 6).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(ranking + 2, 5).Text ' Accepted Apps 2016
        .Cells(ranking, 7).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(ranking + 2, 6).Text ' Variance TY/LY
        .Cells(ranking, 8).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(ranking + 2, 7).Text ' % Variance TY/LY

    End With

 Next ranking
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I cannot understand what is the problem/error

Comment: Is this VBA in Excel (with a reference to a PowerPoint Application object), or in PowerPoint (with a reference to an Excel Application object)?

Comment: It's in excel with a reference to powerpoint application objects etc. Issue it is doesn't work it highlights the very first line of .cells(..... and says object doesn't support this property or method. even when not using 'ranking' and just manually typing it out it gives the same error, it works further up in my code but i just wanted to loop this one as there are more lines to copy across

Comment: Sorry guys seems i solved it myself, first bit of each line should be

.Cell(Ranking, X)
NOT
.cells(Ranking,X)

but the second part should be 'Cells'

Comment: LOL - Microsoft likes to keep us on our toes - just slight differences in object names between applications.